# Hosting Gmail and Google Drive on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm looking to have all my data under one cloud and don't want to split it between AWS and Google Cloud. Is there a way to use the Gmail and the Google Drive interface while hosting the entire operation on AWS?

Comment: Is this a programming question? I think you should rephrase it to be or post it in another forum.

Comment: What do you mean by "hosting the entire operation on AWS"? Hosting _what_?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to "store data on Google Drive but actually store it in your own S3 account", then no -- Google stores data in its own systems.

Interestingly, there are companies that offer storage services similar to Amazon S3 and use the normal S3 API, so that the services look identical (although they might be missing some of the advanced features offered by S3).